# Why are matplotlib images from np array dominated by red?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been ingesting image data from np arrays and adding two additional dimensions so I can use an image processing pipeline which requires RGB data, and the images are heavily dominated by red. Here's what I'm doing, starting with a dataframe of file paths:

```
#get filename
f = files.tail(-1)['name'].values[0]
img = plt.imread(f)
#check if it's an array in 3 dimensions
if len(img.shape) == 2:
    print('not RGB')
    #image sizes vary so get shape
    s = img.shape[0:2]
    dim2 = np.zeros((s))
    dim3 = np.zeros((s))
    pix = np.stack((img, dim2,dim3), axis=2)
    pix = np.true_divide(pix, 255)

    plt.imshow(pix)
```

And a sample of the result:
[image: red images (should be black/white)]

Appreciate your help!

Comment: "RGB" means red, green, blue. Your image data is in the first channel, hence red. You set the green and blue channel to zero explicitely in your code.

Comment: Because you are setting the green and blue components to zero?

Comment: Well that's really silly of me. Is this approach appropriate? What else would you do?

Comment: Appropiate for what? Your plots look nice to me even if I am having a hard time figuring out how your code can possibly generate them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code explains your problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.random.rand(10, 10)

B = np.zeros((*A.shape, 3))
B[:,:,0] = A

C = A.reshape((*A.shape, 1)).repeat(3, 2)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3)

mats = [A, B, C]

for ax, mat in zip(axs, mats):
    ax.imshow(mat)
```

`A` is your grayscale image. `B` is what you did: The values of `A` assigned to the red channel of an RGB image. `C` is most likely what you want: Since you need an RGB image, you just copy the values of `A` two times. Results:

[image]

Left to right: `A`, `B`, `C`